# ensure distinct results when filtering by a joined many-to-one entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

There are 2 entities and a join table.

```
bookplanningmain$edition 1<- bookplanningmain$rendition_edition -> * bookplanningmain$rendition
```

I am porting to Hibernate the sql query.

```
select "id" as "_MxId", "editionid" as "EditionId", "title" as "Title"
from "bookplanningmain$edition" e
where 1=1
and "title" LIKE '%e111%'
and "editionid" = -200
and exists(
   select *
   from "bookplanningmain$rendition" r
   join "bookplanningmain$rendition_edition" r_e
   on r_e."bookplanningmain$renditionid" = r."id"
   where r_e."bookplanningmain$editionid" = e."id"
and "isbn2" LIKE '%978%'
)
```

At first I wanted to use exists(), but did not understand how to use the association in it. Therefore JOIN. I was afraid that due to one to many there would be some duplicate rows, but it seems to work as a distinct by default

```
select e
from BookPlanningMain.Edition e
join e.rendition_Edition r
where 1=1
and title LIKE '%e111%'
and editionId = -200
and isbn LIKE '%978%'
```

The problem starts when I select individual attributes instead of an entity

```
SELECT new map(e.id, e.title)
```

Then there are duplicates. Now I'm forced to use DISTINCT everywhere and it's bad because ORDER BY puts some restrictions on it. How to use EXISTS() properly? Do I have to explicitly compare by `id` in the WHERE clause? Because when using JOIN I don't have to.